# Add a new Header Row at top of existing Data Table in UiPath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am struggling with how to add a new row at the top of an existing data table in UiPath. After going through documentations and tutorials related to data table manipulation, I couldn't find much with regards to same or any simple method to achieve same.

I tried few methods at my end but the addition of new row at the top changed the schema. If I create a new data table with just single header row and would like it to be merged with the existing data table such that it gets inserted at top, then how to do that with least number of steps?

Regards, 
Vanjuli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it with this line of code `dt.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0)`:

All together:
[image]

Build DataTable:
[image]

Invoke code:
[image]

Output:
[image]